# how to replace the null character

Tags: java

In java ,i have editfield whcih takes its input ,in it we can enter 3 digits

when i enter first and third ,leaving 2 digit empty ,how to remove empty digit
thanks

Comment: What sort of edit field is this? I doubt that it's returning you a unicode 0.

Comment: It's not the null character, but white space what you're talking about, I guess

Answer (score 7):

The null character is a character like all others. Its value as a byte is 0. Use \0 to identify it. (Same in C, Perl, C++, C#, etc).

Java:

`String noSpaces = perhapsSpaces.replaceAll("\0", " ");`

`System.out.print(noSpaces + "\n");`

Perl:

`$perhapsSpaces =~ s/\0/ /g;`

`print $perhapsSpaces . "\n";`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove all white space internally in a String (which is what I think you're asking), then you want something like:

```
sText.replaceAll("\\s+", "")
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got "`X_Y`" ("`_`" indicating a missing character) and you want "XY", then

```
String newString = entered.charAt(0) + entered.charAt(2)
```

is the simplest way. But that's only useful for this one particular case. Do you not want to handle missing beginning and end characters too ?

Answer (score 0):

Stripping spaces from a String (don't know if J2ME has StringBuilder so I'll just do ugly String concatenation):

```
String noSpaces = "";
for (int i=0; i<perhapsSpaces.length(); i++)
{
  if (perhapsSpaces.charAt(i) != ' ')
    noSpaces += perhapsSpaces.charAt(i);
}
```

For "better" space handling, perhaps Character.isWhitespace?