# How to remove empty space?

Tags: java, string, java-me

In j2me, I have edit-field which takes its input, in it we can enter 3 digits.

When I enter first and third, leaving 2nd digit empty,

How to remove empty digit?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187147/how-to-replace-the-null-character

Comment: @skaffman: This is about j2me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a replaceAll method like this:

```
public static String replaceAll(String text, String searchString, String replacementString) {
        StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        int pos = 0;
        while ((pos = text.indexOf(searchString)) != -1) {
            sBuffer.append(text.substring(0, pos) + replacementString);
            text = text.substring(pos + searchString.length());
        }
        sBuffer.append(text);
        return sBuffer.toString();
    }
```

Then you can call it this way:

```
text = replaceAll(text, " ", "");
```

Comment: http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr139/java/lang/String.html See the api, there is no String.replaceAll.